# KendoUI Grid Update Issue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I define a grid in my page :

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Grid/GetPerson",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'Get'
                },
                update: {

                    url: function (person) {
                        debugger;
                        return "/Grid/Update";
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: "POST",

                },
                destroy: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                create: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                        Name: { validation: { required: true } },
                        Family: { validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                        Tel: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 430,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "نام" },
            { field: "Family", title: "فامیل" },
            { field: "Tel", title: "تلفن", width: "100px" },
            { command: [{ name: "edit", text: "ویرایش" }, { name: "destroy", text: "حذف" }], title: "عملیات", width: "160px" }],
        messages: {
            editable: {
                cancelDelete: "لغو",
                confirmation: "آیا مایل به حذف این رکورد هستید؟",
                confirmDelete: "حذف"
            },
            commands: {
                create: "افزودن ردیف جدید",
                cancel: "لغو کلیه‌ی تغییرات",
                save: "ذخیره‌ی تمامی تغییرات",
                destroy: "حذف",
                edit: "ویرایش",
                update: "ثبت",
                canceledit: "لغو"
            }
        },
        editable: "popup"
    });
});
```

In `person` parameter in `update` function, i can access changed row by :

```
person.models[0]
```

it gives me :

```
Object {ID:1,Name:"pejman",Family:"kam",Tel:"098787887"}
```

SO i want to send this data to the server, so i have a action in `GridController`:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void Update(TblPerson person)
    {
        //do update
    }
```

for doing it, i try :

```
 url: function (person) {
       return "/Grid/Update/" + JSON.stringify(person.models[0])
  },
```

in the update method, but it doesn't work, how can i do it?
NOTE: when i using above in Network tab of browser give me `Bad Reuest` error:

```
URL:http://localhost:2145/Grid/Update/%7B%22ID%22:1,%22Name%22:%22pejman%22,%22Family%22:%22kam%22,%22Tel%22:%22098787878%22%7D
Status Code:400 Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *kendo.stringify(options.models)* sends your object in JSON string. So I believe that your js code can stay as it is. Just change your Update method in controller to something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Update(string models)
{
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<TblPerson>>(models);

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        //Your action
    }
}
```

The approach above just assume that you can send more models to update. Don't forget *using Newtonsoft.Json*

Comment: This won't work because he's appending the JSON to the URL, it's not sending the data with a POST call.

Comment: He just showed what he tried but his code in the top is working with this. I am using same.

Comment: Right. I guess MVC it's still binding `models` in the query string in spite of being declared as an `HttpPost` action. I didn't think it thoroughly enough, now I got it. :)

Comment: It gives me badrequest error again. and it doesn't call `Update` method in controller, when i send my request in `Network tab`  in browser i see  in `request payload` of my request: `models=%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A1%2C%22Name%22%3A%22%D9%BE%DA%98%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%22%2C%22Family%22%3A%22%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B2%22%2C%22Tel%22%3A%22sss%22%7D%5D`    is it possible that the issue is related to it?

Comment: Well, did you remove _return "/Grid/Update/" + JSON.stringify(person.models[0])_ code and in your transport method have you only update: { url: "/Grid/Update", dataType: "json", type: "post"}? Because parameterMap will handle your data sent to controller.

Comment: @Ademar yes i do it, and it sent to controller request payload, as i mesioned in above comment

Comment: well that's strange because I am using exactly same code and it works for me. I'll try to think what can cause that error ..